# Liferay and Internet Explorer 8 (ie8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, liferay

I use Liferay 6.2-ce-ga3 and I want to create some links in on my site in javascript.

Following the [liferay documentation](http://www.liferay.com/en/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-portlet-urls-in-javascript-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-07-en) I am using

```
var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createURL(baseUrl);
```

where I set the baseUrl in the jsp with

```
baseUrl = '<%= PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, portletDisplay.getId(), themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE) %>';
```

This works fine in firefox or chrome, but if I use Windows and Internet Explorer 8 I get

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; 
SLCC2;.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center 
PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; MS-RTC LM 8)

Timestamp: Thu, 19 Mar 2015 11:40:08 UTC

Message: 'Liferay.PortletURL' is null or not an object
```

What do I have to do to make it work in IE 8? Is there a special liferay js that I need to include?

I can create the links in jsp using the method 2 of the documentation:

```
'<portlet:renderURL >
    <portlet:param name="MYPARM" value="MYVALUE"/>
    <portlet:param name="PAGENAME" value="..."/>
</portlet:renderURL>'
```

For now I will try to create links as much as possible in the jsp, but it would be nice to pass parameters to a link using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, because IE8 is officially supported by LR6.2 (I think by respond.js and other in Bootstrap): see [compatibility matrix](https://www.liferay.com/documents/14/21598941/Liferay+Portal+6.2+EE+Compatibility+Matrix.pdf/3b3fd878-c954-4acc-bd5f-19fb7eb78210)

Watching your error, it seems that Javascript isn't able to find `Liferay.PortletURL` object (or a valid object).

Just a couple of questions: are you sure that there aren't any javascript error before (because that can stop following js instructions).

Comment: I have no errors in the javascript console under firefox. And Internet explorer only told me the error message above. I have used the method 2. of the documentation and this works for me.

Comment: Did you solved by method 2? What is the exact solution? It can be useful for future readers... :)

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate the other way to do it. This does not answer my question, but it circumvents the problem for my application. Thanks for pointing out the need for clarification.

Comment: Ah, ok... you used taglib. By the way, if you aren't really able to solve think to create your own js function to create urls... it's enough to remember portlet params format and create them manually, or to create by taglib your final url with placeholders, then replace it by javascript. It's really NOT an elegant solution, but if you will not be able to solve in other ways... :)